# Storing a Stack in WP7 isolatedStorage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

What is the most simple way to store a Stack type object in isolatedStorage in WP7 development ?

Comment: do you mean an object of type `Stack<T>`? What's in it?

Comment: It would be a stack of events, each event has 3 int values, so it would be Stack<Event>

Answer (score 0):

Can you just serialize it to an isolated file, i.e:

```
public static class IsolatedSerializer
{
    public static void Save<T>(string filename, T t)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(t.GetType());
        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        using (var stream = store.CreateFile(filename))
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(stream, t);
        }
    }

    public static T Load<T>(string filename)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        using (var stream = store.CreateFile(filename))
        {
            return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }   
}
```

Or this won't work on WP7 for some reason?

- I assume you won't serialize the actual `event` - this is quite tricky, and won't work with xml serializer.

Comment: I think I understand better what you're asking now. Have a look here: http://www.imaginativeuniversal.com/blog/post/2010/08/26/WP7-Tip-tombstoning-simplified.aspx